# how to extract a list from another list in OnBindViewHolder in RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder45 holder, int position)
{
    AllClassDataResp allClassDataResp = allClassDataRespList.get(position);
    int classNumb = allClassDataResp.getClassNum();
    List<SectionInfo> list = allClassDataResp.getSectionInfos();
    SectionInfo sectionInfo = list.get(position); // throwing IndexOutOfBounds Exception

    String name = sectionInfo.getSectionName();
    Long id = sectionInfo.getSectionId();
    String classandSec = classNumb + "th" + " - " + name;

    holder.tClassSec.setText(classandSec);
    holder.sectionInfo = sectionInfo;
```

Throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException. I also tried using for Loop but didn't work.

My Pojo Class.

```
public class AllClassDataResp {


@SerializedName("classNum")
@Expose
private Integer classNum;

@SerializedName("sectionInfos")
@Expose
private List<SectionInfo> sectionInfos = null;
```

Can Anyone Tell me how to solve this.

EDITED :

after using for Loop

```
AllClassDataResp allClassDataResp = allClassDataRespList.get(position);
    int classNumb = allClassDataResp.getClassNum();

    List<SectionInfo> sectionInfoList = allClassDataResp.getSectionInfos();

    String classAndSec = "";

    for (SectionInfo sectionInfo : sectionInfoList)
    {
        String name = sectionInfo.getSectionName();

        classAndSec = classNumb + "th" + " - " + name;
    }

    holder.tClassSec.setText(classAndSec);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception because you are already get your object from your list. you have access it sub object.

```
AllClassDataResp allClassDataResp = allClassDataRespList.get(position);

SectionInfo sectionInfo = list.get(position); // throwing IndexOutOfBounds Exception
```

May be possible your list do not contain enough data. Your list size are less than your position and you are try to get those value which is not exist.

**You can get the list value like :**

```
for(SectionInfo sectionInfo : list){
   // your actual sectionInfo object get here.
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it is not displaying according its position.

Comment: i Posted. where did i do mistake?

Comment: @SriKamalTeja Have you understand? and is that work?

Comment: @SriKamalTeja Try this and let me know what you are getting in your textview.

        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (SectionInfo sectionInfo : sectionInfoList)
        {
            String name = sectionInfo.getSectionName();

            String classAndSec = classNumb + "th" + " - " + name;
            stringList.add(classAndSec);

        }

        membersName = TextUtils.join(", ", stringList);
        holder.tClassSec.setText(membersName);

Comment: Excellent Answer. but one More thing, it is separating with comma when it has more than one value. but i need to show on the textView without separating in an order like 1-A on first card and 1-B on next card.

Comment: @SriKamalTeja if this answer has work for you then Can you please upvote this answer.

Comment: @SriKamalTeja Pls can you share image for your requirement.?

Comment: since i dont have reputation credits, i cannot upvote but i accepted your Answer. Ya i'm sharing image please wait.

Comment: i resolved it, the problem is, i was trying to append two lists values and trying to display on textView but their sizes are different, since it is throwing IndexOutOfBounds Exception. And Thanks for helping me. If possible try to upvote my question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your variable list doesn't have the same number of item than the variable allClassDataRespList. So you are trying to access a variable at a non existing index.

Comment: though it doesn't have same variables, does it matter? because i'm trying to get  list of variable using position.

Comment: The index given by the variable position has range between 0 and the integer return in getItemCount() method of your adapter (that return allClassDataRespList.size()). So this number could be higher that the number of element present in your variable list

Comment: Ok. I totally understand the concept of index of a list but in my case i have a class list (allClassDataRespList) consists of sectionsList (sectionInfo) as i mentioned in the question and i want to show data on card view like 1-A, 1-B, 2A etc. Can you tell me how extract Data and show it on card view in onBindViewHolder().

Answer (score 0):

Your code `allClassDataRespList.get(position)` is accessing index that is beyond what is available. Suppose you have the following array

```
allClassDataRespList = new ArrayList<AllClassDataResp>();
allClassDataRespList.add(new AllClassDataResp(...) ); //index 0
allClassDataRespList.add(new AllClassDataResp(...) ); //index 1
allClassDataRespList.add(new AllClassDataResp(...) ); //index 2
```

Now assume you have your function that accesses the objects from the list

```
public AllClassDataResp getItem(int position)
{
    return allClassDataRespList.get(position);
}
```

now to illustrate error you are getting, let us call our function

```
AllClassDataResp existing1 = getItem(0); //works fine
AllClassDataResp existing2 = getItem(1); //works fine
AllClassDataResp nonexisting = getItem(3); //throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

The most common sense would be checking if array size is indeed in such a way that index exists

```
if(position < allClassDataRespList.size())
{
    //exists
}
```

See more on that method on the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int))

As `onBindViewHolder` method of the RecyclerView Adapater, I have never found yet a use case where am given an item to bind that does not exist. There must be a problem with your basic design of the Adapater and how it manages data